# Angularjs blueimp fileUpload manually trigger submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I manually trigger file uploads within an action of an angular controller?

This is my controller

```
  angular.module('angular-app', ['blueimp.fileupload'])
     .controller('NewsController', function($scope, $http) {

    ......

    $scope.SaveNews = function() {           
        var url = baseUrl + '/Post',
            data = $scope.News;
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data
        }).success(function(data) {                   
                    $scope.News = data.Data;


                    --->   something.submit(); // <--- THIS IS THE FILES SUBMIT


                }                
            }).error(function(data) {
                ShowAlert(data.Success);
            });
    };
```

I cannot trigger anything, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
My problem was getting the list of files. I solved this way

```
//The list of files
$scope.$on('fileuploadchange', function (event, files) {
            $scope.Files = files.files;
        });
//The action triggered manually
$scope.SubmitAction = function(){
   $('#fileUploadID').fileupload('send', {files: $scope.Files});
}
```

Pay attention to one thing, every time it is called "fileuploadchange" in the variable "files" you can find only the latest items added!

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation: 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#wiki-programmatic-file-upload

```
$('#your-selector').fileupload('send', {files: your.data});
```